# How to set the environment variable for PHP in Linux?

Tags: php, oracle, environment-variables, mediawiki, tnsnames

I'm implementing MediaWiki with the Oracle Database and therefore I need to add TNS_ADMIN variable to my PHP startup environment.

Q1: How do i add TNS_ADMIN variable to PHP  Startup environment?

Q2: Is there a specifc file to edit in order to add the env varibale? If so where can i find it on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache and the apache2handler [SAPI](http://php.net/php-sapi-name), you can use [SetEnv](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_env.html#setenv); you can also export the variable from the init script that starts the PHP process (works for all SAPIs). For example, on most (older) Linux-based distros, you'll probably find a file named /etc/init.d/apache2 or /etc/init.d/httpd that is a shell script where you can export variables  for that service. Check your OS' equivalent of "man 5 init" for specifics.